# Windows updates failing to install (code 80070005)

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-update

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server.  There are 5 Windows updates sitting waiting for me to install:

[image]

... but when I try, I get the following error message:

[image]

I have tried rebooting, installing each of these 5 updates individually, but no matter what, it always fails, with that same meaningless error message:

> Code 80070005: Windows Update encountered an unknown error.

How to fix this?

Comment: It's a pretty vague and broad error that could mean a whole bunch of things.  Hit up Google and start trying suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was caused my my Antivirus (McAfee).
I disabled it, and the updates have now been applied...

Comment: You should update that, too.

Comment: @MichaelHampton ...or better yet, remove it.

Answer (score 0):

stil no exact and easy resolution available from microsoft.

you can use Subincle, but make sure it should not hamper the production.it will make your security permission default.

Below Article :
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-update/window-update-error-windowsupdate80070005/a9a2c92d-793b-4050-bdb1-720bb97bd78d.